# ¿Cómo puedo restringir el acceso directo a un directorio de mi servidor, pero permitiendo el acceso desde un script php?

Tags: php, apache, permisos

estoy haciendo una aplicación web y necesito almacenar y mostrar imágenes y documentos pdf.

Quería evitar el acceso directo a ellos y a la carpeta del servidor donde están guardados, es decir, que por ejemplo al escribir directamente en la barra de chrome su ubicación o la de la carpeta donde están apareciera un error 403 forbidden y no se permitiera el acceso.

Para ello, cree un archivo .htaccess en la carpeta contenedora con el sigiente contenido:

`Order deny,allow
Deny from all`

Haciendo uso de mi aplicación web, en un documento php, no hay problema a la hora de mostrar documentos pdf de esta manera:

`header('content-type: application/pdf');
    readfile('../../../files/documents/'.$document);`

Sin embargo cuando accedo a las imágenes mediante `<img style=max-width:100% src=../files/documents/'.$document.'>'` se me deniega el acceso y obtengo un código de estado de tipo 403 forbidden

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder visualizar las imágenes desde la aplicación pero restringiendo el acceso directo a las imágenes?

También me gustaría saber por qué puedo acceder a los pdf pero no a la imágenes

Answer (score 1):

No es tan difícil, de hecho de la misma forma en la que muestras los PDFs tienes que mostrar las imágenes. El siguiente ejemplo requiere que implementes tus propios controles de seguridad pero un script como el siguiente:

```
function descargar_archivo($archivo) {
   $ruta_completa = "/mis/archivos/varios/" . $archivo;
   header("Content-length:" . filesize($ruta_completa));
   header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $archivo . '"');
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   return readfile_chunked($ruta_completa);
}

function readfile_chunked($archivo, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $pedazos= 1024 * 1024;
    $buffer = "";
    $cnt = 0;
    $handle = fopen($archivo, "rb");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $partes);
        echo $buffer;
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }
    $estado= fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $estado) {
        return $cnt;
    }
    return $estado;
}

echo descargar_archivo($filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fileid', 513));
```

Toma como input el stream GET, buscar un archivo, lo lee y lo regresa al stream; dicho de otra forma tus imágenes se servirían así:

```
<img src="http://mysitio.com/mi_script.php?fileid=bailarina.jpg">
```

De esta forma preservas tu esquema actual de permisos en el sistema de archivos en donde el intérprete PHP puede leer los archivos pero el servidor web no.

Comment: Cuando cambio el el <img ...> por la llamada a esa función la página donde llamo a las imágenes deja de cargar y me da un error de "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". ¿Puede ser porque el <img> es llamado dentro de un modal que se muestra al clickar en un enlace?

Comment: No debe influir, si muestra la imagen cuando tecleas la URL en el browser entonces debe ser otra cosa. Tienes activado que se muestren los errores en php?